# Wrap html content in span with prototype.js - is it possible?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have the following code on our forum…

`<h3 id="anonymous_element_1">
    <a href="#" class="ipsSidebar_trigger">×</a>
Latest Posts</h3>`

`<h3 id="anonymous_element_2">
    <a href="#" class="ipsSidebar_trigger">×</a>
Popular Posts</h3>`

Is it possible to wrap the Latest Posts and Popular Posts text in a span tag while maintaining the same structure using prototype.js?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this if you have more than one element to put inside the wrapper would be to create an element and then move the other items inside of it.

```
var wrap = Element.new('span', {id: 'whatever'});
wrap.insert($'anonymous_element_1').remove();
wrap.insert($'anonymous_element_2').remove();
```

If you only have one thing to wrap, then the canonical way is like this:

```
$('anonymous_element_1').wrap('span', {[attributes as a hash]);
```